# Cmap is normalised over each column

Tags: python, matrix, colors, rotation

When using plt.cm i.e. a colourmap, the colours for this confusion matrix shown below work fine except for the 1.0 value which then appears to be far too light in colour.

I expect this is something to do with either: The colours wrap such that at 1.0 the colour is set back to a lighter colour (unlikely) or the colour in the box with value 0.692 is in fact meant for that with value 1.0 but my script is constructing the colours in a strange way.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class_names = np.array(['EA','EB','RR Lyrae','Ceph','Dscuti','Noise'])

def pcm(cm,classes,normalize = True,title='Confusion Matrix',cmap=plt.cm.OrRd):
    plt.imshow(cm,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks,classes,rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks,classes)
    cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis =0)[:,np.newaxis]
    cm = np.around(cm,decimals=3)

    thresh = cm.max()/2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]),range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j,i,cm[i,j],horizontalalignment="center",color="white" if cm[i,j]>thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.xlabel('True Species')
    plt.ylabel('Predicted Species')

cnf_matrix = confusion_matrix(np.array(pred_classes)-2,real_classes)
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
plt.figure()
pcm(cnf_matrix,classes=class_names,normalize = True,title = 'Normalised Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: Having looked into it further, I think that the colour is set depending on the value scaled to the other values in the row being considered; if so is there a way to stop this and instead normalise colour scale over the entire matrix?

Comment: I meant column not row on the previous comment

Comment: Problem fixed by putting the line plt.imshow(cm,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap)
after the calculation of the decimals:
cm = np.around(cm,decimals=3)